# Not able to run invoke sqlcmd command with Active Directory Admin in azure function (powershell)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-functions

I am running sql script with invoke-sqlcmd command in Azure Functions powershell.

This is my code :

```
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $adminLogin, $PWord

$Username = $($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().UserName)

$Password = $($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)

$Port = 1433

$cxnString = "Server=tcp:$serverName,$Port;Database=$databaseName;UID=$UserName;PWD=$Password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=Active Directory Password"

$createUserSQLFile = 'C:\filepath\createUser.sql'

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $cxnString -InputFile $createUserSQLFile
```

But I get this error when I run this in Azure Functions Powershell :

> **invoke-sqlcmd : keyword not supported: 'authentication'.**

I believe this error is due to the Authentication in connection string.

When I run this powershell in my local machine, it runs without any error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Edit your question and use the `{}` which is a facility of the editor to paste code in the formatted text so it will be easier to read, understand and reply.

Comment: edited. added snippet

Comment: Sounds like you don't have Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (adal.dll) installed. REF: [Configure your client computers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#configure-your-client-computers)

Comment: Yes. But how do I install it in Azure Functions?